# how to save a text file stored as a cell string of arrays after making changes to it?

Tags: matlab, file-handling

I am a beginner in matlab scripting, i have a text file which i am editing(finding and deleting certain strings). after i do the necessary changes how do i save the file?
for example:

```
io_contents = 'testing.m';
filetext = fileread(io_contents);
expr = '[^\n]*.DataType [^\n]*';
fileread_info = regexp(filetext, expr, 'match');
C = textread('filetext', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
    z=length(fileread_info);
    if z>=1
    C = C(cellfun(@isempty, strfind(C, 'auto')));
    end
```

Every time i run this,it deletes the first match but doesnt save that in the testing.m file and continues iterating. should i open a new file,call testing.m inside it,makes the changes and then save it?thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are working in your local memory, what you need to do is to write your cell `C` into a file.

Assuming your cell is composed by strings you can do, for instance

```
C = {'aa', 'bb'}           % // test
fid = fopen('out','w');    % // output file

cellfun(@(x)fprintf(fid,'%s\n',x),C)  % // write strings to output file

fclose(fid)                % // release resource
```

which gives

```
aa
bb
```

in the output file (`out`).